# Find Observable in Observable Array

Tags: angular, observable

I have an observable Array, looks like

```
obj_array: Array<Observable<SatzDetail[]>> = [];
```

My observable looks like

```
let ob_oj = this.defAPi.getDetailSatz(dsn, date);
```

and I push this observable into the array, like this

```
 this.obj_array.push(ob_oj);
```

Later on I subscribe these array elements

```
Observable.concat(...this.obj_array).subscribe(res => {

            res.forEach(a => { this.detailSatz.push(a) });
        });
```

So far so good. But I want to control, whether an Observable does exist or not bevor I made the push

```
this.obj_array.push(ob_oj);
```

How can I do that? I have to find an specific observable in the array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure but did you try casting `ob_oj` into `Observable`?

Comment: No, ob_oj is from type Observable<SatzOverview[]>. So far so good. That works so far. But how to find an Obserservable before pushing it?

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your problem is you are not interested in duplicate items emitted by the observable and hence you want to check before you push an observable.

What you can try is distinct operator:

```
Observable.concat(...this.obj_array).distinct().subscribe(res => {
     res.forEach(a => { this.detailSatz.push(a) });
});
```

> Angular6 and above:

```
Observable.concat(...this.obj_array).pipe(distinct()).subscribe(res => {
         res.forEach(a => { this.detailSatz.push(a) });
    });
```

This way you don't really need to check what you are pushing.

Comment: Ahh it's different.

The user click on a list item ->push into observable array
The user click on the same item ->"pop" this item from observable array (delete the item).

The second part is missing.

Thanks for your advice.